# How make image sharing to Facebook with link back to content page in website/app like Instagram?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am building an iOS app that let user created some type of images and when user finished doing that they can choose to publish it on their facebook timeline automatically.

I am able to post to user's timeline automatically because user allow publish_permission to our app. And I let my app post an image created by users to their facebook timeline. It went out smoothly. The image appear on Facebook and it displayed that this image is created by my app. But I am not able to provide the link when users click on the name of app to my content page.  How can I do that ? I saw Instagram having this feature and it should drive more engagement to our app.  This is the screenshot of how Instagram does this[image]

This is how my app display it 
[image]

This is the code how I posted image to user's timeline in my iOS app

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = [UIImage imageWithData:,myImage];
photo.userGenerated = YES;

 NSURL *URL =  [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myWebsite.com/profile/%@/item/xxxx]];

photo.caption = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ Created by xxx"];
photo.userGenerated = YES;
photo.imageURL = URL;

FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];    
[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

Do I need to use opengraph or anything else ?  Please help. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can not get that same “View on X” link – Facebook owns Instagram, and therefor Instagram can use some special features likes this, which are not available to 3rd-party app. // What is your “content page” that you want to link to – is it a page where that specific picture is displayed? In that case, you could let users just share that URL, and set the image as the thumbnail for that link using Open Graph meta tags. (That would not be a real photo upload any more than though.)

Comment: Thanks. I just tried checking several major apps. Looks like Polvore can link user to deep page (content page) as well but only in mobile app. As I checked I think they used opengraph to achieve this result but not much benefit to them as they already posted link not the image

Comment: How about sharing an App Links URL? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks, and, configuring the app store ID on your Facebook Application, attribution on Open Grahph Shares, etc.